# LSTM Neural Network gets stuck in a specific state when trying to predict new states over many time periods

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I have built an LSTM neural network for category, or latent state, prediction.

The data is more or less of the form:

- x1 = continuos number from current record
- x2 = continuous number from current record
- x3 = continuous number from current record
- x4 = state value for the current record

Only one one-dimensional variable to be predicted.

- y1 = state value for the next record

Fitted with an LSTM model of the form below:

```
model_lstm = tf.keras.Sequential()
model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (xtrain.shape[1],xtrain.shape[2])))

model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=5, activation = "softmax", input_shape = (xtrain.shape[1],xtrain.shape[2])))

loss_fn =  tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.001)
model_lstm.compile(loss=loss_fn, optimizer=opt, metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
```

Fitting an LSTM model of say this form makes it fit almost perfectly on training and validation data when presented with an individual sequence:

- [x1_t1, x2_t1, x3_t1, x4_t1] = [y1_t1]
- [x1_t2, x2_t2, x3_t2, x4_t2] = [y1_t2]
  .
  .
  .
- [x1_tn, x2_tn, x3_tn, x4_tn] = [y1_tn]

however, it fails when simulating, a sort of walk where the predictions are used directly into the next inputs...

- [x1_t1, x2_t1, x3_t1, x4_t1] = [y1_t1]
- [x1_t2, x2_t2, x3_t2, **y1_t1**] = [y1_t2]
  .
  .
  .
- [x1_tn, x2_tn, x3_tn, **y1_t(n-1)**] = [y1_tn]

In fact it simply gets stuck in a state and doesn't move. Is there any solution to this? I am impressed with the accuracy but obviously it's not very useful unless a person only wanted one prediction at a time that he/she can immediately correct per time step output.